# Visual Studio Setup Project: Huge list of dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

This is Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

I'm using Setup Project (MSI) to create an installer for my VSTO add-in. I have done this stuff numerous number of times in previous versions of VS and haven't ever seen this behavior. VS2015 detects a huge number of dependencies that aren't included in the references of the add-in project. Rebuilding the projects and using **Refresh Dependencies** command hasn't proved any good. Has anyone else experienced this problem or knows a solution?

Here's a snapshot of the **References** section of my add-in project vs. the **Detected Dependencies** list that the setup project shows:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446774/setup-project-is-adding-built-in-net-framework-system-assemblies-to-output

Comment: @Eternal21: No, I didn't. Several months have passed since then and I didn't look at the problem again. One clue that might help you is that these extra dependencies might be the dependencies of some of the included references (e.g. SharpCompress and MVVMLight in the above example). DependencyWalker might be a good tool to dig if that is the case.

Comment: At the moment, my guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the target framework (in my case 4.5.2) is not installed on the deployment machine.  That causes the installer to just dump the required files in the destination folder and be done with it.

Comment: @Eternal21: Deployment machine? How does VS know about deployment machine's status? Maybe u wanted to say *development machine*?

Comment: I was assuming the decision to install all those files in the target folder was done during install time.